# How to create a chain between 2 programs input-to-output?

Tags: input, output, chaining

I have a console program in Linux that when I execute it, it reads some sensors conditions and writes them in the terminal and user can see. Also have another program that when I run, it asks for sensors value and I must put them by hand.

How can I make a connection between these two programs that number one can pass it's values automatically through number 2 and I shall not write them by hand?

For example:
Program number1:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int[10] sens_value=get_sensors_value();
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
std::cout<<sens_value;
return 0;
}
```

Program number 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int[10] sens_values;
for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
std::cin>>sens_values[i];
...etc
return 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make only one program and transform your **main** method in diferent methods and call them in the same program, but you cant *conect* programs.